# html page is too small in mobile web browser

Tags: android, html, mobile

I have an Android app that simply launches the URL to my Java EE web app. I've edited all of the jsp pages for the web app for viewing in a mobile browser (before that the viewed pages were too small to read in the mobile browser). All is good except one html page: my contact page that's linked from my main web app page. It is still too small to read in the mobile browser. If someone could read the following contact html page and tell me what's wrong I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for any replies.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE>Contact</TITLE>

    <META id="META" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" >


<style>


         body {
            background-color: #87CEFA;  
            font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size:0.8em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

</style>


</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <section>
            <header>
                    <h3>Email:</h3>
            </header>
            <p>
                    <span >Support:</span>
                    <span><a href="mailto:[email address]">[email address]</a></span>
            </p>

            <p>
                    <span >General:</span>
                    <span><a href="mailto:[email address]">[email address]</a></span>
            </p>
        </section>

<br><br>

<form action="Startup" method="get">

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Go Back to previous page">
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: which android version/device/browser you use?

Comment: My phone is Android 4.04, Samsung Galaxy Centura, Chrome web browser. Chrome version is 42.0.2311.

Comment: I just tried the Android app in 2 different virtual phones in Android Studio and the contact page views correctly in them. Must be just my phone then. Maybe my Android and Chrome versions are too old or aren't completely compatible for all mobile browser display scenarios.

Comment: My phone says Chrome updates are no longer supported for my version of Android.

Comment: I just went to the contact page in my phone browser and it displayed correctly. I guess before it was displaying a cached version of the page that used the uncorrected html code for mobile web viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to the contact page in my phone browser and it displayed correctly. I guess before it was displaying a cached version of the page that used the uncorrected html code for mobile web viewing.